# What does the '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END do in the CASE expression

Tags: sql, sqlite

I don't understand what exactly is happening in the above statement and what exactly is '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END.

```
String order = "CASE WHEN "
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, "
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + ", "
                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                + " COLLATE NOCASE";
```

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags.  This is clearly an SQL question, not a Jav or Android question.

Comment: Thanks @StephenC I'll keep in mind while posting.

Comment: Learn SQL: Read the [SQLite Documentation](https://sqlite.org/docs.html), in particular, the [`CASE` expression](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) and the [`LIKE` operator](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like).

Answer (score 3):

Case is like `if` statement but can be used with multi conditions:

In your example it means:

If ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME was NOT lIKE '%@%' THEN return 1
ELSE return 2

Concerning the '%@%': 
the % means that there can be certain characters in this place.
It means that the user wants to select all the fields that doens't contain the '@' character whether in the beginning, middle, or end of the text.

Comment: maybe you can have more explain on `'%@%'`

Answer (score 0):

The CASE statement is like an IF statement, it is just more convenient if you want to avoid to have many "ELSE".

The % character is the wildcard character in SQLite. So, NOT LIKE '%@%' means not contains a "@" character (for example an email address).

Comment: Means "doesn't contain an `@` character". Saying that anything with an `@` character is an *email address* is a stretch.